# transform latitude and longtitude to pixel coordinate

Tags: python, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, pixel

I am trying to draw latitude and longtitude unit polygon on an image. Firstly I converted latitude and longtitude to pixel coordinate by these codes:

```
#Coordinates of the image that was taken by satellite.
geometry = [
    [
      [
        37.831375,
        37.319936
      ],
      [
        39.855892,
        37.319936
      ],
      [
        39.855892,
        36.648589
      ],
      [
        37.831375,
        36.648589
      ],
      [
        37.831375,
        37.319936
      ]
    ]
  ]
size = (18029,7418) # Size of the image with 10 meter resolution
x_min, y_min = numpy.min(geometry, axis = 1)[0]
x_max, y_max = numpy.max(geometry, axis = 1)[0]
bbox = [x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max]
#Bounding box of the image that was taken by satellite.

#Coordinates of the interested area. This coordinate is not same in the image because it is too long but this problem occurs for every coordinates. 
coords = (((39.08568996313544, 36.98214695658683), (39.08763215671231, 36.981526940581695), (39.08846916197828, 36.98535695997243), (39.08690784509872, 36.98633898531564), (39.08804795990786, 36.98960402033453), (39.082422961126994, 36.99086807070554), (39.08188800539215, 36.98933904379114), (39.08568996313544, 36.98214695658683)),)
coords = numpy.array(coords)

def coord2px(size, coords,bbox):
    lat, lon = coords[:,:,0], coords[:,:,1]
    x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max = bbox

    x =  size[0] -size[0]*(x_max - lat)/(x_max - x_min)
    y =  size[1] -size[1]*(y_max - lon)/(y_max - y_min)

    
    return numpy.vstack((x,y)).T.astype(numpy.int64)


pixels = coord2px(size,coords,bbox)
"""
pixels are 

[[11170  3685]
 [11187  3678]
 [11194  3721]
 [11180  3731]
 [11191  3768]
 [11140  3781]
 [11136  3765]
 [11170  3685]]

for specified coordinate(coords)
"""
```

After converting latitude and longtitude to pixel position then I draw this polygon on the image by these codes:

```
image = cv2.imread("concatenate.jpg")
image = cv2.flip(image, 0) #I flip the image otherwise it is like reversed.

matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(image)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(pixels[:,0],pixels[:,1], color = 'red',linewidth = 5.0)

matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Then zoomed image is like that:
[image]

the area by red color was drawn by pixel coordinate but it should have been like blue one. Why is it shifted ? I can provide image if you need.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this by hand, rather than using an existing library

Comment: @IanTurton I am so new to here, maybe I don't know the library. Can you say its name and give some resources about what I try to do if there is  ?

Comment: Try shapely or geopandas

Comment: @IanTurton I made some research about them but could not find suitable function to do what I want.

Comment: What projection is the original map? In non-cylindrical projections such as Mercator, one degree of latitude uses a different number of pixels that one degree of longitude.

Comment: @BarryCarter I think it is wgs84

Comment: @IanTurton can you do an example by this libraries ?

Comment: Wait, I don't think WGS84 is a projection? I'm guessing it's Mercator.

Comment: @BarryCarter It is so possible, sorry for my lack of knowledge about the subject. It may also EPSG4326 because I give this parameter to the system when I get data.

Comment: That's also not a projection. A projection is how a map converts latitude and longitude to pixels (in computer graphics)

Comment: @BarryCarter How can we be sure about projection ? Additionaly I take images from [SentinelHub](sentinel-hub.com) maybe this can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138738/discussion-between-barry-carter-and-wtow).

Comment: `x =  size[0] -size[0]*(x_max - lat)/(x_max - x_min)`: Image width seems to be assigned to _x_ axis and related to latitude, but latitude increases in the height direction in north-up spatial references. Are you sure not mixing axes order?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca I changed but pixels became minus because in image x and y order are little bit different. I think they are right but there is a problem like calibration.

Comment: I think `x =  size[1] -size[1]*(x_max - lat)/(x_max - x_min)` can't be negative if wasn't negative before. Are you sure not mixing image axis order?

Comment: BTW, to transform between pixel and spatial coordinates you can use rasterio.transform module.

Comment: Thank you for all help, I solved the problem, the problem was about image shape. I would calculate image shape by a formula but it gives me little bit wrong shape then I used just image's shape and it solved.